# Why Cant I Open any Excel Files, though it opens the Particular file path from the Below code?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, operating-system

The below Code is able to go to the Excact Destination but still it  cant acsess the purticular Excel files for a reason

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("250x140")
root.configure(bg="Light Blue")

def open_file():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Ken Rozairo/Desktop/Calco")
    if file_path:
        df = pd.read_excel("file_path")
        print(df)
        os.startfile(file_path)
    
def open_folder():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    folder_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")], initialdir="C:/Users/Ken Rozairo/Desktop/Calco/DIALOG - SLT CAL.xlsx")
    if folder_path:
        os.startfile(folder_path)

def open_name():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    folder_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")], initialdir="C:/Users/Ken Rozairo/Desktop/Calco/BUN - CAL.xlsx")
    if folder_path:
        os.startfile(folder_path)

file_button = tk.Button(text="GFM", command=open_file)
file_button.grid(row=0, column=10, padx=80, pady=8)

folder_button = tk.Button(text="Finance Reports", command=open_folder)
folder_button.grid(row=1, column=10, padx=80, pady=8)

folder_button = tk.Button(text="CALCO", command=open_name)
folder_button.grid(row=2, column=10, padx=80, pady=8)

tk.mainloop()
```

***I want to Access and Open an Assigned Excel File when the command is given from the Assigned Button***

Comment: Hey, I proposed an edit to your post, you don't need to add ` to each line individually, for code blocks you can just add 3 backticks at the start and at the end, each on their own line.

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**First:** in your `open_file()` function you try to load the DataFrame with `df = pd.read_excel("file_path")`. This does not work since `"file_path"` is a string and not the variable you try to access, so remove the parantheses.

**Second:** aside from this your script is a little messy and has a lot of redundant code (like the instanciating of a root for the file dialog?!). When working with tkinter try to use an OOP approach.

**Third:** You do not need a filedialog if you have a specific path for a file. Simply open the file directly.

Here is how I would do it:

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog


class FileLauncher(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # root settings
        self.title('Launcher')
        self.geometry('250x140')
        self.configure(bg='Light Blue')
        # variables
        self.file_types = [('Excel Files', '*.xlsx')]
        self.init_dir = 'C:/Users/Ken Rozairo/Desktop/Calco/'
        # GUI elements
        self.gfm_button = tk.Button(text='GFM', command=self.print_and_open_file)
        self.gfm_button.grid(row=0, column=10, padx=80, pady=8)
        self.fr_button = tk.Button(text='Finance Reports',
                                   command=lambda i_dir=self.init_dir: os.startfile(i_dir + 'DIALOG - SLT CAL.xlsx'))
        self.fr_button.grid(row=1, column=10, padx=80, pady=8)
        self.calco_button = tk.Button(text='CALCO',
                                      command=lambda i_dir=self.init_dir: os.startfile(i_dir + 'BUN - CAL.xlsx'))
        self.calco_button.grid(row=2, column=10, padx=80, pady=8)

    def print_and_open_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=self.file_types, initialdir=self.init_dir)
        if file_path:
            df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
            print(df)
            os.startfile(file_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fl = FileLauncher()
    fl.mainloop()
```